# Reddit posts from user in android app

Tags: android, api, reddit

I am trying to get all the posts from user from reddit and put this in a list to show in an android app. The problem is, I don't know if the current reddit API supports android in anyway.

Somehow this reddit API wiki makes me confused, so if you people could point me in the right direction, that be be appreciated. :)

Thanks in Advance,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work somehow with sending an HttpGetRequest in android and then just loop through the json respons.